# Proper way to use JQuery $.post

Tags: jquery, forms, post, submit, action

I'm trying to intercept form submittal to perform a test. I'm using the JQuery `submit` event on the form. I an successfully prevent the default action. But I can't seem to manually post the data to the server-side form handler. What am I doing wrong?

*clicktest.html*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //alert("jquery working");
            $('#theform').on('submit', function(event){     
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("submit clicked");
                $('#data').text($('#theform').serialize());
                $.post('http://arielbalter.com/clicktest/clicktest.php', $('#theform').serialize());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="data">data</p>
    <form id="theform" method="POST" action="http://arielbalter.com/clicktest/clicktest.php">
        <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="Text"/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit-button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*clicktest.php*

```
<?php
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    echo $text;
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/u7ayLf9h/

Comment: And how do you know, you're not checking the returned result from the ajax call ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The real goal is a ColdFusion app, not using ajax. So, I will be processing the form data not with PHP, and not expecting anything in return. But the principle is the same. Why isn't the PHP getting the post data via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `response` like this:

```
$.post('http://arielbalter.com/clicktest/clicktest.php',    
   $('#theform').serialize(),
   function(response) {
      alert(response)
   }
);
```

Comment: @abalter Test on `localhost` jsfiddle send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error on `console`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Could you flesh that out a bit, perhaps in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of capturing the form's `.submit` event, I make the button a regular button, and handle it's `.click` event.

The new HTML is:

```
<p id="data">data</p>
<form id="theform" method="POST" action="http://arielbalter.com/clicktest/clicktest.php">
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="Text" />
    <input type="button" id="submit-button" name="submit-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The new JQuery is:

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //alert("submit clicked");
    $('#data').text($('#theform').serialize());
    $.post('http://arielbalter.com/clicktest/clicktest.php', $('#theform').serialize());
    $('#theform').submit();
});
```

The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/xuhn669p/6/